# PDF to PDF/A conversion

Tags: .net, vb.net, pdf, pdfa

I receive many files in PDF format. They come as email attachments. I must supply them to an intranet software. I have written a VB.NET application that reads those emails, collect their text and attachments and fill the form from the intranet software accordingly.

My problem is: the new version of intranet software requires PDF/A compliance. I'm aware of websites that do this conversion, but I wanted to know if there is some executable, library or package that I could include freely in my project to perform this locally in a simpler fashion than robot-browsing another website.

Thank you very much!

Comment: You might look at the products (and maybe even talk to them) PDF-Tools AG (www.pdf-tools.com) has.

Comment: @MaxWyss They have what I need - for $756. Fair or not, I can't have it, for I earn nothing from my own code. That's why I need a free solution.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into evaluating Datalogics APDFL.There are C, C#, and Java sample code that can perform the conversion to PDF/A.

Here's some background on how the PDFAConverter sample works.

Note: By default, this example program opens a file called input.pdf in the
source directory.  It converts this file and saves the output in the executable directory by the name out.pdf.

It demonstrates use of PDFProcessorConvertAndSaveToPDFA() and PDFProcessorConvertAndSaveToPDFX() that allows user to specify (optional)
Callback to Monitor Conversion Progress. The User also has an Option to Cancel the Operation by returning 1 in Callback, if required.

Comment: Sorry, I visited their site and although they have a very rich set of products, they are not free to use.